# google chrome cannot identify jquery-ajax function data result

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I'm trying to do some action based on the jquery-ajax function result
here is a example code:

```
function test(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'testing.php',
        success: function(data) {
            if($.trim(data) == 'OK' )
                alert('success , its ok');
            else
                alert(data)
        }
    })
}
```

It works fine in Firefox and i get the "success its ok" alert, but in Chrome i get "OK" alert. Why doesn't `$.trim(data) == 'OK'` work in Chrome even when the data is equal to "OK" ?

Comment: Have you tried using `console.log(data)` to see what it is? Also, I might try adding the `dataType` option to the AJAX call and making sure it's expecting a specific type...hope this helps!